# Container positioning with navbar, carousel and intro

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar, carousel and intro.

**What I want:**

- Carousel full width and height.
- Navbar on top over the carousel
- Intro under the carousel.

**What I have now:**

- Carousel full width and height but images in carousel is only full width and not the height
- Navbar on top over the carousel (Success)
- Intro starts under the navbar and suppose to start under carousel

**html**

```
<div class="carousel"></div>
<div class="navbar"></div>
<div class="intro"></div>
```

**css**

```
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100% }
.navbar {}
.intro {}

.carousel {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a new container for the carousel and navbar. Then I positioned the navbar absolutely inside it (glued it to the top).

Here is the code (run the snippet at the bottom):

```css
html, body
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}

#carouselNavBarContainer
{
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}

.carousel
{
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding:10px
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  border:1px solid #09f;
}

.carousel img
{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}

.navbar 
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    z-index:2;
    border:1px solid #f00;
    padding:10px;
}

.intro
{
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="carouselNavBarContainer">
    <div class="carousel"><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>This is the carousel.</div>
    <div class="navbar">NAVBAR GOES ON TOP</div>
  </div>
  <div class="intro">Intro on the bottom</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have parent div for 'carousel' and 'navbar' and add styles like below -

```
.parentDiv{
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
}

  /* Carousel full width and height with images */

  .carousel{
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    padding-top:50px;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  /* note that images will be be stretchy */
  .carousel img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
  }

  /* Navbar on top over the carousel */
  .navbar{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;  /* for Example */
    z-index:9; /* greater than carousel */
  }
```